# Is there a way to start pandas add_prefix column index from 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have gone through [pandas.Dataframe.add_prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html). I have a set of columns being dynamically created, so am using pd.df.add_prefix for those columns.

For example, newly created columns are:

```
column0         column1          column2
```

It's starting from 0. Is there a way to start column naming from 1, like:

```
column1         column2          column3
```

**Edit:**

Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[34007, [3330193, 349723]], [126063, [349723,7901731]]], 
columns=['prod_1', 'prod_2'])
```

Code:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['prod_2'].values.tolist()).add_prefix('column').join(df['prod_1'])
```

Output that I got:

```
column0       column1        prod_1
3330193       349723         34007
349723        7901731        126063
```

Expected output:

```
column1       column2        prod_1
3330193       349723         34007
349723        7901731        126063
```

**Please note only names of generated columns change in expected output, values remain same**

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Please make your question clearer. How did you begin with those column names in the first place?

Comment: `df.rename(columns=lambda x: f"column{int(x)+1}")` ?

Comment: Thanks @anky, in case there are some more additional columns other than the above? For example, if the dataframe has columns like `id|name|column0|column1|column2` and I want to apply that logic only to `column0|column1|column2`. So how could we modify it for this case as well. Since `column0|column1|column2` these are being dynamically created, we would not know, it might create columns upto `column n`

Comment: @omdurg you should edit your question with a dataframe and expected output in that case :)

Comment: I have made the edits with dataframe @anky, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `df.rename` to rename the columns with f strings:

```
out = (pd.DataFrame(df['prod_2'].values.tolist())
       .rename(columns=lambda x: f"column{int(x)+1}").join(df['prod_1']))
```

---

```
   column1  column2  prod_1
0  3330193   349723   34007
1   349723  7901731  126063
```

Comment: Hello @anky , i do have the same question but in different manner, mind to take a look on it ? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286625/python-reformatting-pandas-dataframe#comment113686841_64287244) thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, I am currently out of my place . Will take a look and try something at night if that's ok :)

Comment: thank you. np i will keep search for a solution too.