# Python reformatting Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do have the following `DataFrame`

```
   draw_date midday_daily evening_daily midday_win_4 evening_win_4
0 2020-10-05          582           577         5490          4958
1 2020-10-06          318           176         2137          9956
```

Which am trying to convert it into the following `Shape`:

```
    draw_date   draw_period     winning_numbers                wn_01    wn_02   wn_03   wn_04   wn_sum
0   2020-10-05  Midday                5 4 9 0                     5        4       9       0    18
1   2020-10-05  Evening               4 9 5 8                     4        9       5       8    26
2   2020-10-06  Midday                2 1 3 7                     2        1       3       7    13
3   2020-10-06  Evening               9 9 5 6                     9        9       5       6    29
```

That's what I've achieved yet:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'draw_date': {0: ('2020-10-05 00:00:00'), 1: ('2020-10-06 00:00:00')}, 'midday_daily': {0: '582', 1: '318'},
                             'evening_daily': {0: '577', 1: '176'}, 'midday_win_4': {0: '5490', 1: '2137'}, 'evening_win_4': {0: '4958', 1: '9956'}})

df.drop(df.columns[1:3], axis=1, inplace=True)
df['draw_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['draw_date'])


print(df)
```

Output:

```
   draw_date midday_win_4 evening_win_4
0 2020-10-05         5490          4958
1 2020-10-06         2137          9956
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit more verbose/descript approach

```
def split_numbers(df, column, prefix=None):
    split_col = df[column].astype(str).map(list)
    out = pd.DataFrame(split_col.tolist()).astype(int)
    out.columns += 1
    return df.join(out.add_prefix(prefix))

(df.filter(regex=r"(?:draw_date|win)")                   # Select the draw_date and "win" columns
 .rename(columns=lambda col: col.replace("_win_4", ""))  # Remove suffix "_win_4"
 .melt(                                                  # Reshape the data
     id_vars="draw_date", 
     var_name="draw_period", 
     value_name="winning_numbers")
 .pipe(split_numbers, "winning_numbers", prefix="wn_0")   # Extract out the winning numbers and assign back to df
 .assign(                                                # Create a sum column
     wn_sum=lambda df: df.filter(like="wn").sum(axis=1))                 
 .sort_values(                                           # sort by draw_date and draw_period to line up with OP
     ["draw_date", "draw_period"], 
     ascending=[True, False])              
)
```

outputs:

```
    draw_date draw_period  winning_numbers  wn_01  wn_02  wn_03  wn_04  wn_sum
0  2020-10-05      midday             5490      5      4      9      0      18
2  2020-10-05     evening             4958      4      9      5      8      26
1  2020-10-06      midday             2137      2      1      3      7      13
3  2020-10-06     evening             9956      9      9      5      6      29
```

Comment: the `column` argument is the name of the column I want to split the numbers out of. So in this case I want to split all of the numbers apart from the "winning_numbers" column.

Comment: Hello, am just checking if it's possible to change the start of `wn_0` to starting from `wn_01` and so on without the need of change column name? i see that i can add `0` to prefix but I'm lost within the part of `pipe` to add the argument of start `+1`

Comment: Inside of the `split_numbers` function, we're making a DataFrame whose columns default to `[0, 1, 2, 3]` (this dataframe is stored in the `out` variable. All you need to do is change `[0, 1, 2, 3]` to `[1,2,3,4]` before the call to `add_prefix`. I'll update the answer with how I would achieve this.

Comment: Thank you a lot. that's really helpful. i appreciated all your time and efforts taken.

Answer (score 1):

```
# set index and stack
stack = df.set_index('draw_date').stack()
# map list to your stacked series and create a new frame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, stack)), index=stack.index)
# sum the rows column-wise
new_df['sum'] = new_df.astype(int).sum(1)
# add the winning numbers back
new_df['winning numbers'] = stack
print(new_df)


                          0  1  2  3  sum winning numbers
draw_date                                                
2020-10-05 midday_win_4   5  4  9  0   18            5490
           evening_win_4  4  9  5  8   26            4958
2020-10-06 midday_win_4   2  1  3  7   13            2137
           evening_win_4  9  9  5  6   29            9956
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but how about the date itself to be duplicated as well ?

Comment: It is "duplicated" it is just a multi-index. Just do `new_df.reset_index()`